# JDBC with Android - Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean Error

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc

I've tried almost every method available on net to rectify the error, but it keeps popping up.

Used patched `ojdbc6` to work on `logging.properties` (`oracle.jdbc.level=OFF`) etc. Nothing is working.

I am using `jdbc6` for Android application. About a week back, the app was working fine (Simple select statement after connection). Haven't changed anything, but suddenly its stopped working.

The Error is

```
W/oracle.jdbc: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:322)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:201)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:197)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
        at com.example.duke.jdbcoracle.MainActivity$ConnectToOracle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
        at com.example.duke.jdbcoracle.MainActivity$ConnectToOracle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.duke.jdbcoracle-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:322) 
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:201) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45) 
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:197) 
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
        at com.example.duke.jdbcoracle.MainActivity$ConnectToOracle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132) 
        at com.example.duke.jdbcoracle.MainActivity$ConnectToOracle.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
    12-09 23:13:50.420 4414-4450/com.example.duke.jdbcoracle D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

And My Code is :

```
try {
    //Load the Driver Class
    //
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    //Create the Conneciton Object
    //
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.103:1521:xe", "root", "starblazer"
    );
    //Create the Statement Object
    Statement statement=connection.createStatement();

    //Execute Query
    ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from users");

    while(resultSet.next()){
        result = result + resultSet.getString(1)+ " " + resultSet.getString(2) + "\n";
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1)+ " " + resultSet.getString(2));
    }

    //Clsoe Connection
    connection.close();

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    e.getMessage();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After Trying and failing for past 3 days, i came up to a part , where i don't need to put any CLASSPATH etc anywhere. I don't know if the solution is correct , but it works.

Just copy ojdbc6.jre to

Linux

```
/usr/lib/jvm/YOUR_ORACLE/jre/lib/ext/
```

On Windows

```
C:/program files/java/jre_yourversion/lib/ext/
```